# Managing Active Directory from Oracle

Tags: oracle, active-directory

I have a database in oracle, my task is to create/update a user in Microsoft Active directory running on different server, when a user detail is entered / updated in Oracle table. 

If its not possible then what is the best way to achieve this. 

Currently we are doing it by running a code written in C# which reads from oracle and does job in AD, it triggers from user creation package but some times triggering fails and whole process fails. User details are updated in DB but not in AD.

Oracle is running at different server. User details are entered in DB through a different package.

Comment: Maybe you can rewrite it into Java(via ldap) and use Java stored procedure.

Comment: @ibre5041 Can you suggest any online site / work to get help / roadmap to do that process.